# Font for hindi unicode to pdf using itextsharp

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have creating pdf using itextsharp c#, for unicode hindi font used 'ARIALUNI.TTF', but when i create pdf, hindi font is not properly showing as input. So, how to get Hindi font in pdf properly.
Can any other unicode font used for it? or any other resolution?
Here is my code & html...

```
 private void fillgridview()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("Name"), new DataColumn("HindiName") });
        dt.Rows.Add("India", "भारत");
        dt.Rows.Add("China", "चीन");
        dt.Rows.Add("Australia", "ऑस्ट्रेलिया");
        dt.Rows.Add("United States", "अमेरिका");
        dt.Rows.Add("Canada", "कनाडा");
        dt.Rows.Add("Russia", "रूस");
        dt.Rows.Add("Itli", "इटली");
        dt.Rows.Add("France", "फ्रांस");
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind(); 
    }
    protected void btnExportPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.DataBind();              
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir") + @"\fonts\ARIALUNI.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable table = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable(GridView1.Columns.Count);
        int[] widths = new int[GridView1.Columns.Count];
        for (int x = 0; x < GridView1.Columns.Count; x++)
        {
            widths[x] = (int)GridView1.Columns[x].ItemStyle.Width.Value;
            string cellText = Server.HtmlDecode(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[x].Text);
            //Set Font and Font Color
            iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
            font.Color = BaseColor.WHITE;
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell cell = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell(new Phrase(12, cellText, font));
            //Set Header Row BackGround Color
            cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.BLUE;
            table.AddCell(cell);
        }
        table.SetWidths(widths);
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (GridView1.Rows[i].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < GridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    string cellText = Server.HtmlDecode(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text);
                    //Set Font and Font Color
                    iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
                    font.Color = BaseColor.BLACK;
                    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell cell = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell(new Phrase(12, cellText, font));
                    //Set Color of row
                    if (i % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        //Set Row BackGround Color
                        cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.YELLOW;
                    }
                    table.AddCell(cell);
                }
            }
        }
        //Create the PDF Document
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {  
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        pdfDoc.Add(table);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();        
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);         
        //Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.End();
        }
    }






<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="300" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Blue"
    HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" RowStyle-BackColor="Yellow" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White"
    RowStyle-ForeColor="Black" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="12">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="200px" DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="200px" DataField="HindiName" HeaderText="Hindi Name" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnExportPDF" runat="server" Text="ExportToPDF" OnClick="btnExportPDF_Click" />

Output:
[<img src="~/AAA.jpg" width="300" height="100">][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUpnG.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I got stuck in the same situation recently. Couldn't find any solution on the internet. Now I got a tricky solution.

Sharing here to help anyone.

I have win10 and it has Kundli NormalA Regular font preinstall.

To see fonts in system - open C drive- Windows - Fonts.

I right click on that and one option appeared - Compress to "HINN.rar"

So I tried HINN.TFF

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir") + @"\fonts\HINN.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);

iTextSharp.text.Font Hindiheadingfonta = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 16, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD);
```

After that open MS Office and choose font Kundli.
Type whatever you want to type in Hindi Font.
Copy that text and paste to VS studio.
बिजेन्द्र in MS Word will be pasted as fctsUæ in C#.

```
PdfPCell Cell15B = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("**fctsUæ**", Hindiheadingfonta));
```

And Done.

Comment: were you able to find any other cleaner way to remove dependency on VS Studio?